# ag-grid theme malfunction using vuetify in vueJS 2

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, vuetify.js

I am using ag-grid in my project which uses vuetify.js and is based on vueJS. I am facing problems with the ag-grid themes. Whenever I use the ag-material theme the outcome is different from the one shown ag-grid website. I just get a very basic theme when I add material theme. Can anyone help?

Comment: please provide more details/code in plunker. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure you import both

```
import "/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "/node_modules/ag-grid/dist/styles/theme-material.css";
```

and then, make sure you include both classes `<ag-grid-vue class="ag-material ag-theme-material">`

Comment: also you might want to set `gridOptions.rowHeight` to something (I chose 48) because the default doesn't look great

Comment: I was not including the ag-theme-material class, but even after including it I see no change.

Comment: dunno what's happening then, it would be great if you could create a Plunker or CodePen to replicate the problem